# Time series Econometrics demonstration

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, time-series

[image]

Hey there! Can anyone help me with this? I am able to arrive to expression (3) from (2) by using the lagged variable and make the variation from $Y_t$ and then divide to the right such that $\beta_0 = \alpha_0 /(1-\alpha_1)$. But I cannot arrive to (4) any help?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where users must demonstrate effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site. Using only images as proof of work is insufficient. for more details see:https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. Read it more closely.